# Possible to disable Java autoboxing?

Tags: java, autoboxing

The "Generics (Updated)" Java tutorial at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

defines a simple Box class:

```
public class Box {
    private Object object;

    public void set(Object object) { this.object = object; }
    public Object get() { return object; }
}
```

and states:

*Since its methods accept or return an Object, you are free to pass in whatever you want, provided that it is not one of the primitive types.*

Every primitive I pass to the set method works without compilation error. Is there any way to prevent the autoboxing that automatically wraps the primitive if I did want it to break?  And more generally: is there a way to manually prevent autoboxing?  I'm using Java 7.

Comment: I answered this question, but can you explain why you would need this?

Comment: Presumably if you told the compiler to compile expecting source from a version prior to autoboxing, then it would skip it.  The `-source` compiler option allows you to specify a source version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying to read the generics tutorial pretty carefully and it struck me that there really are no limitations on what you can pass in to the set method: primitives are just converted to an Object (so they *can* be passed to the method) and returned that way with get. Then I wondered if there was any "user control" on that process.

Comment: It is kind of ironic in that it's a "strongly typed" language and all the generic stuff, eg, is oriented towards making typing even stronger, but you can have a mistaken parameter and due to autoboxing it will be swallowed hook, line, and sinker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there a way to manually prevent autoboxing?

The only sure way would be use a version of Java earlier than Java 5, which was when autoboxing was introduced.

Or maybe compiling with a `-source` flag that specifies Java 1.4 source compatibility would do it.  Note: this *won't work* with `javac` in Java 9 or later, because support for `-source` less or equal to 5 has not been removed from `javac`.

Doing either would be a really bad idea for anything other than experimentation.  You would also lose a LOT of other important Java language features by reverting to the Java 1.4 level; e.g. generics, enums, and so on.

In short, autoboxing / unboxing is a fundamental part of the modern Java language and it can't be turned off and on at will.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. A primitive type provided where a reference type is expected will be boxed automatically (provided the types match).