# Can I get compilation or runtime error while inserting primitive into List?

Tags: java

The following code is valid:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(1);
```

This is because compiler make boxing/unboxing automatically.
My question is: can I somehow get compilation (or runtime) error in such situation?

I already try:
1) method that return primitive:

```
int foo(){
    return 2;
}

list.add(method());
```

2) anonymous class from java 8:

```
list.add(((Function) (ignored) -> 3).apply(""));
```

UPD:
We can parametrize List to `List<Object>` or even to `List<Integer>` the result will be the same - it's work. My question is "how can I fool autoboxing mechanism?"

Comment: What objects do you want to allow inserting into the List?

Comment: You can always add anything to `List<Object>` AFAIK.

Comment: If you use generics instead of [raw types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) then at least you would get an error if it was, for example, a `List<String>` instead of a `List<Integer>`. (You should not use raw types anyway, see the link).

Comment: @Eran , I can't answer to your question, because I haven't any problem working with generics, my question is theoretical

Comment: `List<Object>` can hold any object, `List<Integer>` can hold `Integer` and `int`, the latter through boxing.  What do you have in mind here?

Comment: @Jesper I update my question. You are right that we need to use generics, but it was out of scope of my question, because my code is work and I ask how to break it)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "List<Object> can hold any object" yes! And `int` isn't Object it's primitive, and I want to see some error when I pass `int` to `List<Object>`

Comment: Just to clarify - you want this to work `list.add(new Integer(1))` but not this `list.add(1)`?

Comment: an `int` is a primitive that will be autoboxed into `Integer` for this insertion. Simply because the JVM will try to match `add(int)` but can't, so it will convert it into `Integer` to search for `add(Integer)` and that will be possible because you have a List<Object> so `add(Object)` match

Comment: The only way to fool the autoboxing mechanism seems to be using old java versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568608/possible-to-disable-java-autoboxing

Comment: There is no way to explicitly turn off auto-boxing. But why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev yes. But it is not a pretension to Java, I like this autoboxing. I would like to know about exceptions from "auto"-boxing

Answer (score 2):

You won't fool typing system, but you can always fool the reader of your code (don't try this at home)

```
class MyList implements List<Integer> {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void add(Integer value) {
        // Call actual implementation
    }        

    // Overload
    public void add(int value) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No autoboxing allowed!");
    }

}
```

Another way to achieve similar effect would be by creating your own wrapper-type and using it as list parameter instead:

```
public class IntValue {

    public final int value;

    public IntValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}

// ...

List<IntValue> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new IntValue(1)); // will compile
list.add(1); // won't compile
```

Comment: Makes no sense at all. `List<Integer> myList = new MyList(); myList.add(2)` - oops!

Comment: @kan true, it will only work if you'll use `MyList list = new MyList()`. Nevertheless, that's how I understood question of OP - show some way in which `someList.add(1)` will fail.

Comment: Yeah, but enforcing use of only `MyList` is not simpler problem than the problem in the question. I.e. Now instead of forbidding `myList.add(2)` you also need to forbid using `List<Integer>`.

Comment: You're right, but honestly - I don't see any practical benefit of using `MyList` whatsoever. So, I approached question more like a programming puzzle. Nevertheless, I added a more practical solution for the problem to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fool compiler, it is in Java Language Spec. Apparently it's possible to use some code check-tools such as PMD or findbugs, e.g.: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#BX_BOXING_IMMEDIATELY_UNBOXED and probably you could write additional custom rule for it to check your specific situations.